# kernel menuconfig not saving to file

Tags: linux-kernel

I am using `make menuconfig` to set up a kernel (5.2.3). When I save the config the file only contains some comments and no options whatsoever.  This happens no matter if I save to `.config`, `something.config`, `/tmp/something.config` etc. After saving I can walk through the menus and I still see my options set up correctly.

I never had problems with menuconfig before (since the 2.4 era). I am running `menuconfig` as root on SystemRescueCd 6.0.3, btrfs, there is obviously free space on the partition available.

This is the saved config file:

```
#
# Automatically generated file; DO NOT EDIT.
# Linux/x86 5.2.3 Kernel Configuration
#

#
# Compiler: gcc (Gentoo 8.3.0-r1 p1.1) 8.3.0
#

#
# General setup
#

#
# IRQ subsystem
#
# end of IRQ subsystem

#
# Timers subsystem
#
# end of Timers subsystem

#
# CPU/Task time and stats accounting
#
# end of CPU/Task time and stats accounting

#
# RCU Subsystem
#
# end of RCU Subsystem

#
# Kernel Performance Events And Counters
#
# end of Kernel Performance Events And Counters
# end of General setup

#
# Processor type and features
#

#
# Performance monitoring
#
# end of Performance monitoring
# end of Processor type and features

#
# Power management and ACPI options
#

#
# CPU Frequency scaling
#

#
# CPU frequency scaling drivers
#

#
# shared options
#
# end of CPU Frequency scaling

#
# CPU Idle
#
# end of CPU Idle
# end of Power management and ACPI options

#
# Bus options (PCI etc.)
#
# end of Bus options (PCI etc.)

#
# Binary Emulations
#
# end of Binary Emulations

#
# Firmware Drivers
#

#
# EFI (Extensible Firmware Interface) Support
#
# end of EFI (Extensible Firmware Interface) Support

#
# Tegra firmware driver
#
# end of Tegra firmware driver
# end of Firmware Drivers

#
# General architecture-dependent options
#

#
# GCOV-based kernel profiling
#
# end of GCOV-based kernel profiling

#
# GCC plugins
#
# end of GCC plugins
# end of General architecture-dependent options

#
# Partition Types
#
# end of Partition Types

#
# IO Schedulers
#
# end of IO Schedulers

#
# Executable file formats
#
# end of Executable file formats

#
# Memory Management options
#
# end of Memory Management options

#
# Networking options
#

#
# Core Netfilter Configuration
#

#
# Xtables combined modules
#

#
# Xtables targets
#

#
# Xtables matches
#
# end of Core Netfilter Configuration

#
# IP: Netfilter Configuration
#
# end of IP: Netfilter Configuration

#
# IPv6: Netfilter Configuration
#
# end of IPv6: Netfilter Configuration

#
# DCCP CCIDs Configuration
#
# end of DCCP CCIDs Configuration

#
# DCCP Kernel Hacking
#
# end of DCCP Kernel Hacking

#
# Queueing/Scheduling
#

#
# Classification
#

#
# Network testing
#
# end of Network testing
# end of Networking options

#
# Packet Radio protocols
#

#
# AX.25 network device drivers
#
# end of AX.25 network device drivers

#
# CAN Device Drivers
#

#
# CAN USB interfaces
#
# end of CAN USB interfaces
# end of CAN Device Drivers

#
# Bluetooth device drivers
#
# end of Bluetooth device drivers

#
# Device Drivers
#

#
# PCI controller drivers
#

#
# Cadence PCIe controllers support
#
# end of Cadence PCIe controllers support

#
# DesignWare PCI Core Support
#
# end of DesignWare PCI Core Support
# end of PCI controller drivers

#
# PCI Endpoint
#
# end of PCI Endpoint

#
# PCI switch controller drivers
#
# end of PCI switch controller drivers

#
# PC-card bridges
#

#
# Generic Driver Options
#

#
# Firmware loader
#
# end of Firmware loader
# end of Generic Driver Options

#
# Bus devices
#
# end of Bus devices

#
# Partition parsers
#
# end of Partition parsers

#
# User Modules And Translation Layers
#

#
# RAM/ROM/Flash chip drivers
#
# end of RAM/ROM/Flash chip drivers

#
# Mapping drivers for chip access
#
# end of Mapping drivers for chip access

#
# Self-contained MTD device drivers
#

#
# Disk-On-Chip Device Drivers
#
# end of Self-contained MTD device drivers

#
# LPDDR & LPDDR2 PCM memory drivers
#
# end of LPDDR & LPDDR2 PCM memory drivers

#
# Protocols
#

#
# NVME Support
#
# end of NVME Support

#
# Misc devices
#

#
# EEPROM support
#
# end of EEPROM support

#
# Texas Instruments shared transport line discipline
#
# end of Texas Instruments shared transport line discipline

#
# Intel MIC & related support
#

#
# Intel MIC Bus Driver
#

#
# SCIF Bus Driver
#

#
# VOP Bus Driver
#

#
# Intel MIC Host Driver
#

#
# Intel MIC Card Driver
#

#
# SCIF Driver
#

#
# Intel MIC Coprocessor State Management (COSM) Drivers
#

#
# VOP Driver
#
# end of Intel MIC & related support
# end of Misc devices

#
# SCSI device support
#

#
# SCSI support type (disk, tape, CD-ROM)
#

#
# SCSI Transports
#
# end of SCSI Transports
# end of SCSI device support

#
# Controllers with non-SFF native interface
#

#
# SFF controllers with custom DMA interface
#

#
# SATA SFF controllers with BMDMA
#

#
# PATA SFF controllers with BMDMA
#

#
# PIO-only SFF controllers
#

#
# Generic fallback / legacy drivers
#

#
# IEEE 1394 (FireWire) support
#
# end of IEEE 1394 (FireWire) support

#
# CAIF transport drivers
#

#
# Distributed Switch Architecture drivers
#
# end of Distributed Switch Architecture drivers

#
# MII PHY device drivers
#

#
# Enable WiMAX (Networking options) to see the WiMAX drivers
#

#
# Input device support
#

#
# Userland interfaces
#

#
# Input Device Drivers
#

#
# Hardware I/O ports
#
# end of Hardware I/O ports
# end of Input device support

#
# Character devices
#

#
# Serial drivers
#

#
# Non-8250 serial port support
#
# end of Serial drivers

#
# PCMCIA character devices
#
# end of PCMCIA character devices
# end of Character devices

#
# I2C support
#

#
# I2C Hardware Bus support
#

#
# PC SMBus host controller drivers
#

#
# ACPI drivers
#

#
# I2C system bus drivers (mostly embedded / system-on-chip)
#

#
# External I2C/SMBus adapter drivers
#

#
# Other I2C/SMBus bus drivers
#
# end of I2C Hardware Bus support
# end of I2C support

#
# PPS clients support
#

#
# PPS generators support
#

#
# PTP clock support
#

#
# Enable PHYLIB and NETWORK_PHY_TIMESTAMPING to see the additional clocks.
#
# end of PTP clock support

#
# Native drivers
#

#
# ACPI drivers
#

#
# Intel thermal drivers
#

#
# ACPI INT340X thermal drivers
#
# end of ACPI INT340X thermal drivers
# end of Intel thermal drivers

#
# Watchdog Pretimeout Governors
#

#
# Watchdog Device Drivers
#

#
# PCI-based Watchdog Cards
#

#
# USB-based Watchdog Cards
#

#
# Multifunction device drivers
#
# end of Multifunction device drivers

#
# Multimedia core support
#

#
# Media drivers
#

#
# Supported MMC/SDIO adapters
#

#
# Media ancillary drivers (tuners, sensors, i2c, spi, frontends)
#

#
# Customise DVB Frontends
#

#
# Tools to develop new frontends
#
# end of Customise DVB Frontends

#
# Graphics support
#

#
# I2C encoder or helper chips
#
# end of I2C encoder or helper chips

#
# ARM devices
#
# end of ARM devices

#
# ACP (Audio CoProcessor) Configuration
#
# end of ACP (Audio CoProcessor) Configuration

#
# drm/i915 Debugging
#
# end of drm/i915 Debugging

#
# Display Panels
#
# end of Display Panels

#
# Display Interface Bridges
#
# end of Display Interface Bridges

#
# Frame buffer Devices
#

#
# Frame buffer hardware drivers
#
# end of Frame buffer Devices

#
# Backlight & LCD device support
#
# end of Backlight & LCD device support

#
# Console display driver support
#
# end of Console display driver support
# end of Graphics support

#
# HD-Audio
#

#
# Set to Y if you want auto-loading the codec driver
#

#
# Set to Y if you want auto-loading the codec driver
#

#
# Set to Y if you want auto-loading the codec driver
#

#
# Set to Y if you want auto-loading the codec driver
#

#
# Set to Y if you want auto-loading the codec driver
#

#
# Set to Y if you want auto-loading the codec driver
#

#
# Set to Y if you want auto-loading the codec driver
#

#
# Set to Y if you want auto-loading the codec driver
#

#
# Set to Y if you want auto-loading the codec driver
#

#
# Set to Y if you want auto-loading the codec driver
#

#
# Set to Y if you want auto-loading the codec driver
#

#
# Set to Y if you want auto-loading the codec driver
#
# end of HD-Audio

#
# HID support
#

#
# Special HID drivers
#
# end of Special HID drivers

#
# USB HID support
#
# end of USB HID support

#
# I2C HID support
#
# end of I2C HID support

#
# Intel ISH HID support
#
# end of Intel ISH HID support
# end of HID support

#
# Miscellaneous USB options
#

#
# USB Host Controller Drivers
#

#
# USB Device Class drivers
#

#
# NOTE: USB_STORAGE depends on SCSI but BLK_DEV_SD may
#

#
# also be needed; see USB_STORAGE Help for more info
#

#
# USB Imaging devices
#

#
# USB port drivers
#

#
# USB Miscellaneous drivers
#

#
# USB Physical Layer drivers
#
# end of USB Physical Layer drivers

#
# MMC/SD/SDIO Host Controller Drivers
#

#
# LED drivers
#

#
# LED driver for blink(1) USB RGB LED is under Special HID drivers (HID_THINGM)
#

#
# LED Triggers
#

#
# iptables trigger is under Netfilter config (LED target)
#

#
# RTC interfaces
#

#
# I2C RTC drivers
#

#
# SPI RTC drivers
#

#
# SPI and I2C RTC drivers
#

#
# Platform RTC drivers
#

#
# on-CPU RTC drivers
#

#
# HID Sensor RTC drivers
#

#
# DMA Devices
#

#
# DMA Clients
#

#
# DMABUF options
#
# end of DMABUF options

#
# Microsoft Hyper-V guest support
#
# end of Microsoft Hyper-V guest support

#
# Speakup console speech
#
# end of Speakup console speech

#
# Android
#
# end of Android

#
# Gasket devices
#
# end of Gasket devices

#
# Common Clock Framework
#
# end of Common Clock Framework

#
# Clock Source drivers
#
# end of Clock Source drivers

#
# Generic IOMMU Pagetable Support
#
# end of Generic IOMMU Pagetable Support

#
# Remoteproc drivers
#
# end of Remoteproc drivers

#
# Rpmsg drivers
#
# end of Rpmsg drivers

#
# SOC (System On Chip) specific Drivers
#

#
# Amlogic SoC drivers
#
# end of Amlogic SoC drivers

#
# Aspeed SoC drivers
#
# end of Aspeed SoC drivers

#
# Broadcom SoC drivers
#
# end of Broadcom SoC drivers

#
# NXP/Freescale QorIQ SoC drivers
#
# end of NXP/Freescale QorIQ SoC drivers

#
# i.MX SoC drivers
#
# end of i.MX SoC drivers

#
# IXP4xx SoC drivers
#
# end of IXP4xx SoC drivers

#
# Qualcomm SoC drivers
#
# end of Qualcomm SoC drivers

#
# Xilinx SoC drivers
#
# end of Xilinx SoC drivers
# end of SOC (System On Chip) specific Drivers

#
# IRQ chip support
#
# end of IRQ chip support

#
# PHY Subsystem
#
# end of PHY Subsystem

#
# Performance monitor support
#
# end of Performance monitor support

#
# Android
#
# end of Android

#
# HW tracing support
#
# end of HW tracing support
# end of Device Drivers

#
# File systems
#

#
# Caches
#
# end of Caches

#
# CD-ROM/DVD Filesystems
#
# end of CD-ROM/DVD Filesystems

#
# DOS/FAT/NT Filesystems
#
# end of DOS/FAT/NT Filesystems

#
# Pseudo filesystems
#
# end of Pseudo filesystems
# end of File systems

#
# Security options
#

#
# Kernel hardening options
#

#
# Memory initialization
#
# end of Memory initialization
# end of Kernel hardening options
# end of Security options

#
# Crypto core or helper
#

#
# Public-key cryptography
#

#
# Authenticated Encryption with Associated Data
#

#
# Block modes
#

#
# Hash modes
#

#
# Digest
#

#
# Ciphers
#

#
# Compression
#

#
# Random Number Generation
#

#
# Certificates for signature checking
#
# end of Certificates for signature checking

#
# Library routines
#
# end of Library routines

#
# Kernel hacking
#

#
# printk and dmesg options
#
# end of printk and dmesg options

#
# Compile-time checks and compiler options
#
# end of Compile-time checks and compiler options

#
# Memory Debugging
#
# end of Memory Debugging

#
# Debug Lockups and Hangs
#
# end of Debug Lockups and Hangs

#
# Lock Debugging (spinlocks, mutexes, etc...)
#
# end of Lock Debugging (spinlocks, mutexes, etc...)

#
# RCU Debugging
#
# end of RCU Debugging
# end of Kernel hacking
```

Comment: are you running hte process as root or with sudo? or as your regular user?

Comment: As root, I am logged in as root (anyway - if permissions were the issue I would expect to have no file at all, not a partially filled file).